# UISplitViewController with three controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working with developing an iPad application. In that i have to display two table views and one web view in a single view. UISplitViewController allows to add two controller only. Please any one help me.

Answer (score 2):

`UISplitViewController` cannot be configured to use more than 2 sections. If you want to have this functionality in a view controller, you have to write your own. Matt Gemmell's open-source [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad) might be a good place to start your coding.

Of course, you can also just add the three views as subviews to a plain `UIViewController` subclass.